# Error: /linux_amd64/bytes.a: not a package file

Tags: go

I am trying to install 'vet' tool using go get, and I am getting this error:

```
root@ubuntu:~/docker# go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/vet
# code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/vet
../go/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/vet/asmdecl.go:10: import /root/go/pkg/linux_amd64/bytes.a: not a package file
```

I tried to find the solution on internet, couldn't find anything helpful. Could you guys please help me figure out what could be causing this? TIA.

Comment: The Go project has moved to Github, so try `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet`.

Comment: I'd recommend working with Go a regular user then using `sudo` to install the binaries, to minimize how often a command can damage your system.

Comment: @Ainar-G Tried that, it's the same error.

Comment: What does `go version` output?

Comment: @Ainar-G It's 1.2.1, should I upgrade to 1.4.2?

Comment: @Pensu Yes. vet tool is usually built for the latest Go version. This might be the issue.

Comment: @Ainar-G okay, let me try that and get back! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was I was using go 1.2.1, I upgraded it to 1.4.2 and everything is working fine now. Thanks, @Ainar-G for pointing it out.